# React Native Mobile Application - Generating a graph and converting to a PDF within react native

Tags: react-native, pdf-generation, graphing, react-native-chart-kit

We're developing a react native mobile application where we need to generate several different types of graphs (plots, charts, line, etc.) and then convert those graphs into PDF format where we could download or send the graphs as pdf files outside the in-app visualization/rendering of them. Currently we are using react-native-chart-kit, and haven't been able to come up with an easy solution yet. We are open to using a different library if one exists that has similar graphing capabilities to that library and can easily generate pdf's from the graphing data. At the moment, all we can think of doing is to send the graphing data to a web server where we have access to other graphing libraries (js, react web, python, etc.) generate the pdf data then send it back to the mobile application. This isn't ideal, as we'd prefer to do everything directly in the mobile app.

Does anyone have any experience generating graphs within a react-native application and also exporting those graphs as pdf files? Any library we might have overlooked, or an easier solution we haven't though about? Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of hits here, but I also cross posted this on reddit and got some traction. I'm posting a link here as the answer in case anyone else comes across this post:

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/v1wm0o/generating_a_graph_and_converting_to_a_pdf_within/

The two best answers we debated between (both valid):

> You could potentially use https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot. It will “screenshot” anything within a particular View and you can then do what you want with the image data. Perhaps even find a way to write it to a PDF file?

and the other solution is to just do the pdf rendering and graph generation on server-side, though that means this would be an online only feature.